# Calculating time of infinite slab of proto-stellar gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, astrophysics

I was trying to calculate the free-fall time of an infinite slab of gas.
What I did was obtaining the gravitational field outside the slab of uniform initial density and thickness $2Z_0$ which was (I'm not sure): $g = -4G\rho_0Z_0 = \frac{d^2z}{dt^2}$ and then I integrated twice to obtain $z(t) = -2G\rho_0Z_o t^2 + Ct + D$ where $C$ and $D$ are just arbitrary constants that I have to obtain. Am I on the right track?

Update: I found $C$ and $D$ to be $C = 0$ and $D = Z_0$ and solving $t = \sqrt{\frac{Z_0}{2G\rho_0Z_0}}$

Answer (score 2):

We can expand the path of a particle in the $z$ direction in a Maclaurin series, as follows:
$$z(t)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{i!}\left.\frac{d^iz}{dt^i}\right|_{z=0}$$
where $\frac{d^iz}{dt}$ is the $i$th time derivative of $z$. If the acceleration is constant in space, then
$$\frac{d^iz}{dt^i}=0\text{ for }i>2\to z(t)=z_0+v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$$
where $z_0=z(0)$, $v_0=v(0)$, and $a=g$. You should recognize this from kinematics. Assuming that $z_0=Z_0$ and $v_0=0$, and plugging in for $g$, we get
$$z(t)=Z_0-2G\rho_0Z_0t^2$$
which is what you got. Therefore, when $z=0$, you indeed get the final expression you derived. You have
$$t(z=0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2G\rho_0}}$$
This is the freefall time $t_{ff}$, which is also on the order of the dynamic time $t_{\text{dyn}}$.